# Is there a way to see what activity iPhoto is doing with Flickr?

Tags: photos.app

.Is there any way to see what activity is going on in iPhoto behind the scenes?
Below is what I am seeing on OS X 10.8/iPhoto 11 (the arrows are spinning.)

I'm guessing iPhoto is updating Flickr or being updated by Flickr, I'd just like to know what is going on and I can't seem to find any "show status" option.

[image: iPhoto sidebar]

I'd like to be able to see is iPhoto is updating Flickr or if Flickr is updating iPhoto.  Something along the lines of...

- Flickr updated the keywords for photo xxx.jpg
- Flickr updated the description for photo yyy.jpg
- iPhoto uploaded photo zzz.jpg to Flickr
- iPhoto set tags for photo zzz.jpg on Flickr to "Some tags"

I suppose that would be the log of what is happening (not sure if that is explained well.)  Something inside of iPhoto would be nice but a third party app would be OK.

I tried the console app as was suggested with no luck (I could be missing something obvious) and I don't think snitch would know the details of what is being updated - I think it just shows network activity.

Comment: What are you trying to see? the communication, the actual data transfer, who is doing what ? the sync process ? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Buscar웃 - see my edit...

Comment: Many ways to accomplish that. One is try your console to see who is doing what. Another would be to monitor your Traffic with something like Little Snitch. Write a script...